# Append Command to file in CMD Script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, output, echo

This appears foolish question but, I need to add the instruction like text string, but add other lines less that I need.

```
tasklist /fi "SessionName eq services" | find /I "Tomcat" | find /I ".exe"
```

I trying with:

```
@echo off
set "IniCatching=%date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%-%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,5%"
set theFile=%~n0_%IniCatching%.txt
set "tasklistecho=echo tasklist /fi ^"SessionName eq services^" ^| find /I ^"Tomcat^" ^| find /I ^".exe^""
echo Before>>%theFile%
call %tasklistecho%>>%theFile%
echo After>>%theFile%
```

But, this appears that try to show the result (is not treated like string text else command).

Other form:

```
@echo off
set "IniCatching=%date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%-%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,5%"
set theFile=%~n0_%IniCatching%.txt
set "tasklistinst=tasklist /fi ^"SessionName eq services^" ^| find /I ^"Tomcat^" ^| find /I ^".exe^""
echo "echo..">>%theFile%
echo tasklist:>>%theFile%
echo "inst..">>%theFile%
echo %tasklistinst%>>%theFile%


I have in the file (wServ_wFiles_20141122-170025.07.txt):

"echo.."
tasklist:
"inst.."

In my prompt (not in my file) I have:

tasklist /fi "SessionName eq services" | find /I "Tomcat" | find /I ".exe">>wServ_wFiles_20141122-170025.07.txt

Like you see, the value and ">>" filename is treated like only one String....
```

when I try with

```
echo "%tasklistinst%">>%theFile%
```

I have this:

```
FIND: Parameter format not correct
```

Help please...

I want to include my command inside of my file...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try without `echo` :

```
%tasklistinst%>>%theFile%
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you store the string in a variable? This is not necessary, and usually the simplest way is the better:

```
@echo off
set "IniCatching=%date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%-%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,5%"
set theFile=%~n0_%IniCatching%.txt
(
echo Before
echo tasklist /fi "SessionName eq services" ^| find /I "Tomcat" ^| find /I ".exe"
echo After
) >> "%theFile%"
```